All derivations of the WItt algebra are inner
I have seen this result stated but not proven anywhere. This is of course related to the first cohomology of the Witt algebra with values in the adjoint module, and it has been proven in https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.08433 that indeed $H^1(\mathcal{W},\mathcal{W})=0$. I would be very glad if someone knew of a proof if this can be proven directly by computing derivations.

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

In section $3.3$ of your cited arXiv paper it is written: In $[3]$, the first algebraic cohomology of the Witt and the Virasoro algebra was computed, e.g., with $H^1(W,W)=0$. Here $[3]$ is the paper by Martin Schlichermaier, who computed the derivations
$$
H^1(W,W)={\rm Der}(W)/{\rm ad}(W).
$$
More generally, the derivations of generalised Witt algebras have been computed explicitly, see for example here.
